# Public path for API Gateway configured to use Cognito Authorizer

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have a Lambda being exposed to the world through API Gateway. The default authorizer is configured as a Cognito user pool and everything works fine.

I need to be able to expose just one of the endpoints without requiring the client to provide an authorization.

I'm using AWS SAM for defining the API and I couldn't find a way to specify an exception for the default authorizer.

How could this be done?

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for your suggestion. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it is in fact possible to disable the authorizer for one of the endpoints.

Simply set:

```
  Properties:
    Auth:
      Authorizer: NONE
```

More information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiauth.html